# How do use OpenOffice components without installing OpenOffice.org?

Tags: c#, .net, openoffice.org

I'm working on solution for printing office documents based on OpenOffice.org UNO. My project is writing on C# .net. So my question is - it possible to use only required OpenOffice components without installing complete OpenOffice.org. My problem - deploying solution for end users. Thanks for advance.

Comment: If you don't want to run the OOo setup you might want to have a look at the portable edition.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also check out the [ODF Toolkit](http://odftoolkit.org)